# PHP Selecting from table 1 and inserting in table 2 with id return be 0 on table 2

Tags: php, database, html-select

first sorry for my english. I have a problem on my isset  Here's the codes:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $insert = $_POST['insert'];
} 
{
    require('./clanconfig.php');

    $cln = $_POST['clanname'];
    $cms = $_POST['mesa'];

    $checkup    = "SELECT id FROM clan WHERE cname='$cln'";
    $upsql = mysqli_query($conn, $checkup);

    while($srcclan=mysqli_fetch_array($upsql) )
    {
        $checked = $srcclan['id'];
    }

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO clanrequest (clanid, plname, message, playerid) VALUES('$cln', '$uname', '$cms', '$player_id')";       
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die();
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Problem is While searching on table1 with a Post value it's okay but while inserting on table 2 with a id of table 1 and  on table 2 adding but value is only 0 on id column

Html:

```
<form class="clan-form-join action="clanjoin.php" method="post">
<?php
require('./clanconfig.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clan";
$sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='clanname'>";

while($sonuct=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2) )
{
    $cnamer = $sonuct['cname'];
    echo '<option value=" '.$cnamer.'">'.$cnamer.'</option><br />';
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html><br>";
echo'<b>Message</b><br><textarea name="mesa" rows=3 cols=40></textarea><br/>';
echo'<input type="submit" name="insert" class="clanbutton" value=" Send Application ">';
?>
</form>
```

Here's the html codes, i select the details of clan in a clan table and when member select the clan name and insert the button the codes sent with a clan name selected like test clan in isset value and in the isset select the id of clan  selected on option value clan name on table clan and return to insert clan request with name,id of player and where id of clan the problem is id of clan adding automatically 0 without add real id of clan

Comment: What are `$insert` and `$checked` used for? And where do you set `$uname` and `$player_id`?

Answer (score 0):

All the code for inserting should be inside the `if (isset($_POST['insert']))`. You only have the variable assignment there (and you never even use that variable), you have the rest of the code in a separate block (there's no purpose to putting it in a block).

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $insert = $_POST['insert'];
    require('./clanconfig.php');

    $cln = $_POST['clanname'];
    $cms = $_POST['mesa'];

    $checkup    = "SELECT id FROM clan WHERE cname='$cln'";
    $upsql = mysqli_query($conn, $checkup);

    while($srcclan=mysqli_fetch_array($upsql) )
    {
        $checked = $srcclan['id'];
    }

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO clanrequest (clanid, plname, message, playerid) VALUES('$cln', '$uname', '$cms', '$player_id')";       
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die();
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: in my .php file the insert line is already in if(isset($_POST['insert'])) { ... } thats i found weirdly here the problem, insert from all but in clan id row insert only 0 so the problem on select id in clan table with clan name selected on option by player here the problem can't select id of clan with selected by player to insert id of clan in clanrequest table ..

Comment: You have `if(isset($_POST['insert'])){$insert = $_POST['insert'];}`. You end the `if` block after the assignment, the rest is not part of the `if`.